# VS 2015 C# - ElapsedEventHandler not firing in Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, service

I have developed my first C# Service in VS 2015, but I cannot get my ElapsedEventHandler method to fire. I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace UpdateEnvironmentService
{
    public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer = null;
        public Scheduler()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            this.timer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(1000); //timer intraval in milliseconds
            this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.UpdateData);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            Library.WriteLog("Data Updater Started ");
        }

        private void UpdateData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Library.WriteLog("Got to update Data ");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer = null;
            Library.WriteLog("Data Updater Stopped ");
        }
    }
}
```

The line **Data Updater Started** gets printed to my log file, but I never end up seeing **Got to update Data** or even **Data Updater Stopped**. It seems my ElapsedEventHandler is never firing. Anybody have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) for the `System.Timers.Timer` class.

Most examples and usage of the timer, tends to avoid setting `Enabled` directly and instead relies on the `Start` and `Stop` methods.

On a side-note, I would recommend that in the age of `Task`, that you approach the problem in a different way:

```
namespace UpdateEnvironmentService
{
    public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tcs;
        public Scheduler()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Library.WriteLog("Data Updater Started ");
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Runner, _tcs.Token);
        }

        private async void Runner()
        {
            Library.WriteLog("In runner");
            var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            while(!_tcs.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Library.WriteLog("Waiting...");
                await Task.Delay(delay, _tcs.Token);
                UpdateData();
            }
            Library.WriteLog("Cancellation requested; exiting runner");
        }

        private void UpdateData()
        {
            Library.WriteLog("Got to update Data ");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _tcs.Cancel();
            Library.WriteLog("Data Updater Stopped ");
        }
    }
}
```

This approach removes the need for a timer, and instead introduces asynchrony from the task, allowing the threadpool to manage the delay; it also has the benefit of introducing nicer cancellation control, which means it can even be cancelled while it's waiting for the delay!